# Using Variables in a column Function in VBA as argument

Tags: vba

I am basically looking to search for a value in an excel sheet and then select the entire column in which that exists.

```
Sub Test()


Dim address As String
Dim extract As String


Rows("1:1").Select
address = Selection.Find(What:="Date").address
extract = Mid(address, 2, 2)                          'extract value= Say AA
```

'' I want to select the entire column and change its format

```
Columns("AA:AA").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"


   End Sub
```

Is there a way I can do something like     `Columns(extract:extract).Select`

Thanks in advance for your time... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can all of it in 1 single row of code ;)

```
Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Date").entirecolumn.numberformat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
```

Comment: As a Note, this will throw an error if `Date` is not found in the first row.